# How To change Background image Dynamicaly in Android..?

Tags: android, layout

I want to change background image in android layout (android:background) dynamicaly with alpha value changing (changing opacity ). 
when changing one image to another it should going  smoothly

how can I do that ?
cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer it from Property Animation in [android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

when your sequence changes, the animation should be call